# eBay API Access Token Issue: The requested scope is invalid, unknown, malformed, or exceeds the scope granted to the client

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, authorization, ebay-api

I'm working with the eBay API and encountering an issue during the OAuth process. I'm trying to receive an `access_token` through this URL `https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/identity/v1/oauth2/token`

I'm making a POST with this data (please, also, see the Postman screenshot below):

```
- Headers: 
  - Content-Type: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
  - Authorization: <Base64 encoded client ID and secret>
- Body (x-www-form-urlencoded):
  - grant_type: client_credentials
  - scope: https%3A%2F%2Fapi.ebay.com%2Foauth%2Fapi_scope https:%3A%2F%2api.ebay.com%2oauth%2api_scope%2sell.account
  - redirect_uri: <My redirect URL>
```

[image]

After making the POST request, I get the following response:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_scope",
    "error_description": "The requested scope is invalid, unknown, malformed, or exceeds the scope granted to the client"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed a scope "**Authorization Code Grant Type**" and "
**Client Credential Grant Type**" even if you assigned "**grant_type**" is "**client_credentials**"

Authorization Code Grant Type

```
https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.account
```

Client Credential Grant Type

```
https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope
```

So have to use same "**Client Credential Grant Type**" scopes

I demo two same category scopes from "**Client Credential Grant Type**"

```
https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.guest.order
```

[image]

Username and Password copy from your Application Keys (client id and client secret) - the following image.

[image]
You can get the scope list from here

```
https://developer.ebay.com/my/keys
```

[image]

**Client Credential Grant Type**

| Scope | Heading Description |
| --- | --- |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope | View public data from eBay |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.guest.order | Purchase eBay items anywhere without signing in to eBay |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.item.feed | View curated feeds of eBay items |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.marketing | Retrieve eBay product and listing data for use in marketing merchandise to buyers |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.product.feed | View curated feeds of products from the eBay catalog |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.marketplace.insights | View historical sales data to help buyers make informed purchasing decisions |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.proxy.guest.order | Purchase eBay items anywhere, using an external vault for PCI compliance |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.item.bulk | Retrieve eBay items in bulk |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.deal | View eBay sale events and deals |

**Authorization Code Grant Type**

| Scope | Heading Description |
| --- | --- |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope | View public data from eBay |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.order.readonly | View your order details |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.guest.order | Purchase eBay items anywhere without signing in to eBay |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.marketing.readonly | View your eBay marketing activities, such as ad campaigns and listing promotions |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.marketing | View and manage your eBay marketing activities, such as ad campaigns and listing promotions |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.inventory.readonly | View your inventory and offers |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.inventory | View and manage your inventory and offers |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.account.readonly | View your account settings |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.account | View and manage your account settings |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.fulfillment.readonly | View your order fulfillments |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.fulfillment | View and manage your order fulfillments |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.analytics.readonly | View your selling analytics data, such as performance reports |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.marketplace.insights.readonly | View product selling data to help you make pricing and stocking decisions |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/commerce.catalog.readonly | Search and view eBay product catalog information |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/buy.offer.auction | View and manage bidding activities for auctions |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/commerce.identity.readonly | View a user's basic information, such as username or business account details, from their eBay member account |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/commerce.identity.email.readonly | View a user's personal email information from their eBay member account. |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/commerce.identity.phone.readonly | View a user's personal telephone information from their eBay member account |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/commerce.identity.address.readonly | View a user's address information from their eBay member account |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/commerce.identity.name.readonly | View a user's first and last name from their eBay member account |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/commerce.identity.status.readonly | View a user's eBay member account status |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.finances | View and manage your payment and order information to display this information to you and allow you to initiate refunds using the third party application |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.payment.dispute | View and manage disputes and related details (including payment and order information) |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.item.draft | View and manage your item drafts |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.item | View and manage your item information |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.reputation | View and manage your reputation data, such as feedback |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.reputation.readonly | View your reputation data, such as feedback |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/commerce.notification.subscription | View and manage your event notification subscriptions |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/commerce.notification.subscription.readonly | View your event notification subscriptions |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.stores | View and manage eBay stores |
| https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.stores.readonly | View eBay stores |

Comment: @KylianMbappe, Thanks for your accepting, can you give me upvote too?